# Question on stack overflow

Tags: attacks, buffer-overflow, memory, c, stack-overflow

I am preparing for an exam in Computer Security and doing a past-exam without soluions, so I wanted to check if my reasoning holds on a question about stack overflow. Below is the C code in question. The goal is to make the function `do_something()` execute, no matter if pwd is "abcd" or "1234".

My thought is to overflow the variable `usertype` inside the `init()` function. Firstly, am I correct in that the stack during the execution of this function would look like:

```
                   |----------------|
                   |Return Address  |
                   |----------------|
                   |Frame Pointer   |
                   |----------------|
                   |usertype        |
                   |----------------|
```

and if so, if an attacker inputs a `usertype` that floods into Frame Pointer and overwrites the Return Address with the address of `do_something()`, we achieve what is asked for in the question?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy/paste the text and use the code formatting tool.

Comment: Is the link/image broken?

Comment: No, it's just more difficult to read, and if we want to copy it to run it ourselves, we can't

Comment: How is main called in this case?